# Trusting Hoverfly java certificate programmatically

Tags: java, ssl, mocking, keystore, hoverfly

Using Hoverfly-java to mock web services in unit tests, and using HttpClient as web client, found that hoverfly proxy settings are propagated properly using `useSystemProperties()` however I still have TLS error: unknown certificate, I have to add certificate manually to keystore using

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpectoLabs/hoverfly/master/core/cert.pem
sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias hoverfly -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file cert.pem
```

I need Hoverfly SSL context to be added without the above two commands, I have tried:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.useSystemProperties().setSSLContext(SomeTestClass.hoverflyRule.getSslConfigurer().getSslContext()).build();
```

but still have TLS errors, any ideas?

I know it is possible to run above two commands from java code using `ProcessBuilder` but this will have security issues as it needs sudo access and unneeded vulnerability (that didn't work too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting [Hoverfly support](https://gitter.im/SpectoLabs/hoverfly#) I had it work as follows

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            //.setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager) //this causes TLS errors so I commented it out until this final issue is solved.
            .setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(2, true))
            .setKeepAliveStrategy(new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy())
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .setDefaultHeaders(headers)
            .useSystemProperties()
            .build();
```

I still have a problem on using `setConnectionManager()` (it causes TLS errors again), these are the settings I need to add for the newly created `HttpCleint`

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(1000);
poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(1000);
```

**UPDATE**

Solved issue, after searching and contacting hoverfly support I found [similar problem](https://github.com/SpectoLabs/hoverfly-java/issues/137), sol I solved it using

```
private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager getPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager() {
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsocketFactory = null;
    try {
        sslsocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault(), new DefaultHostnameVerifier());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                                                                .register("https", sslsocketFactory)
                                                                .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
                                                                .build();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry); 
    poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(1000);
    poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(1000);
    // Used these settings instead of constructor parameters (long timeToLive, TimeUnit timeUnit)
    poolingConnectionManager.closeIdleConnections(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return poolingConnectionManager;
}
```

I wish Hoverfly could do all this hassle instead.